# Trying To Compile But Missing Headers?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, compiling, sound-blaster

So I'm trying to update my sound card driver but I need to compile first.

After entering the sudo make command, I run into errors, missing files, etc.

See link.
[Terminal_Lines](http://pastebin.com/F48v023B)

I've installed the build-essentials with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential`

Apparently I'm missing something but don't know what. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to note:

1. It seems you are tryimg to install a driver last updated in 2008, which would be written for Linux kernel version 2.6 on a Linux 3.0 system. This will very likely not work.
2. Practically all source tarballs you download have a configure script you should run befire running make, was there one and did you?
3. Some googling tells me that the card is supported in ALSA, so compiling and installing manually should not be needed.
4. If you have working, but bad sound, some people seem to be happier after switching to OSS4 and doing away with PulseAudio.

Comment: Would upgrading the sound card do the trick? It's an older box, say 2006ish.

Comment: I have working sound only coming out of the rear speakers, which in itself seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but if you created the 'Sound' directory, try to rename it to 'sound'. I could be way off here because I don't know anything about the package you're trying to build/install. My second guess would be that you may need some of the `*-dev` variants of some packages, which often have the header files needed to build against.